Line Clip or Extend To Fit Polygon in same perspective
I am having a polygon and line. Line start and end points are touches the polygon edges. If I add a different offset point to polygon points, the line should extend or shorten with same perspective.
Picture-1 is original polygon and line.

Picture-2 is extended/shortened polygon.

I need to draw the line in picture 2 as it in the picture 1 means it should be in same aspect ratio.
